# В кастомном хуке функция setState не обновляет state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

Вот мой код, по его завершению массивы как были пусты, так и остались.

```
const useGetLoadData=(whatyouwant)=>{
    const auth=getAuth()
    const storage=getStorage()
    const [dataPosts,setDataPosts]=useState([])
    const db=getFirestore()
    const [dataImg, setDataImg]=useState([])
    const getLoad=async(whatyouwant) => {
      if(whatyouwant==='posts'){
        const arr=[]
        const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "posts"));
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          arr.push(doc.data())
          arr.sort((prev, next) => next.index - prev.index)
          setDataPosts([...dataPosts, doc.data()])
          console.log(dataPosts)
        })
      }
      if(whatyouwant==='storageImg'){
        const imagesListRef = ref(storage,'images'+auth.currentUser.uid+'/');
        listAll(imagesListRef).then((response) => {
            response.items.forEach((item) => {
                getDownloadURL(item).then((url) => {
                  setDataImg((prev) => [...prev, url]);
                });
            });
        });
      }
    }  
    useEffect(() => {
      getLoad(whatyouwant)
    }, [])
    
     
}
export default useGetLoadData
```

Comment: Почему вы так решили?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ты про вот это место?

```
setDataPosts([...dataPosts, doc.data()])
console.log(dataPosts)
```

При работе со стейтом нужно помнить что это действо асинхронное. Т.е. твой вызов

setDataPosts([...dataPosts, doc.data()])

Сразу не изменит значение `dataPosts`...

Для работы со стейтом в цикле можно использовать СБ-функцию

```
setDataPosts(old => [...old, doc.data()])
```

Либо собрать данные в цикле и только после цикла их все записать один раз в стейт.

Comment: Странно... Я пытался сначала записывать все данные в массив, потом изменять стейт, но это не работало (можешь увидеть, у меня локал arr создан).